# Measuring await time in Node

Tags: javascript, async-await, profiling

Let's say I have a function in Node

```js
const my_function = async () => {
  await sub_function_1();
  await sub_function_2();
  await sub_function_3();
}
```

I could profile how long it takes my_function to run with:

```js
let t0 = new Date()
await my_function()
let t1 = new Date()
let elapsed_ms = t1 - t0
```

But that wouldn't show me how long each of the sub_functions took to run.  Similarly, I would add profiling code around each of the sub_functions, but that wouldn't show me which one of the sub-sub functions took the longest amount of time to run.

Is there a way, for a given function call, the gather all of the awaited functions underneath that call, along with how long each took to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

what about a wrapper function which take a array of functions and runs them sequentially?

```
//simulating a lengthy request
const sub_function = (time) => {return new Promise((res,rej) => setTimeout( () => res(true),time  ) )}

const new_list = [
    {handler:sub_function(90), alias:"sub_function_1"},
    {handler:sub_function(150), alias:"sub_function_2"},
    {handler:sub_function(350), alias:"sub_function_3"},

]

const calculate_max_time = async list =>{
    const time_passed = []
    for (const func of list) {

        const time = Date.now()
        await func.handler
        const time2 = Date.now()
        time_passed.push({alias:func.alias, value:time2 - time})
    }
    const max_time = time_passed.reduce( (max,func) => max.value > func.value ? max : func)
    console.log(max_time)
}

calculate_max_time(new_list)
```

Comment: The issue with this approach is it's not any better than the manual approach above.  Once you determine that my_function is taking a long time, you need to set up profiling to see if sub_function_1, 2 or 3 is the culprit.  Once you determine sub_function_1 is taking majority of the time, you need to set up more profiling to see which of its "sub_sub_functions" is taking up most of the time.  My goal is to gather the times for ALL awaited functions underneath a function call, and sort them by time waiting.  Similar to a flame graph, but for time waiting.

Comment: @Dave you can always log them a file (using a logger) , read the file and generate the graph. As a example: winston logger outputs to `.json` which should be pretty easy to use and generate graphs